# Wrong HTC phone type attached to android market

Tags: google-account

I have a htc desire z and accidently put htc vision
How can it be changed.

I cannot download a program from android market for my phone as it thinks is a Htc vision

Comment: How did you add it to your account? The phone should identify itself to the Market, you shouldn't even have the ability to put in the wrong phone type.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTC Vision](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/HTC_Vision#Intro) is the Desire Z, it is also known as the G2 on T-Mobile.

This is basically the name that HTC gives the device before it sells it to carriers. Some carriers want it rebranded. I also believe that HTC decided to publicly call the Vision the Desire Z, but I assure you, they are the same device.